# background image overlay with text not even giving the background-image

Tags: html, css

I tried to get a linear gradient on my background from top to bottom but the background image which I was getting originally now disappeared. However if I used the normal background-image property I was getting my image properly.

```css
    background: linear-gradient(rgba(0,0,0,0.6),rgba(0,0,0,0.9),url(bg.jpg));
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-size: cover;
    background-attachment: fixed;
    height: 100vh;
```

It should give the proper background without a gradient but instead the image disappeared. Somebody pls help!

Comment: What debugging have you done? Use your browser's dev tools inspect facility to check exactly what CSS is being applied. You will see a warning by the background setting. You have a syntax error, the bracketing is wrong, you have included the url in the linear gradient.

Answer (score 1):

Please try this.
It will work properly.

```
background-image: linear-gradient(rgba(0,0,0,0.6),rgba(0,0,0,0.9)),url(bg.jpg);
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-size: cover;
    background-attachment: fixed;
    height: 100vh;
    opacity:0.5;
```

Answer (score -1):

Use opacity:0.1;
I hope this will fix your problem

Answer (score -1):

Use the following syntax:

```
background: linear-gradient(rgba(0,0,0,0.6),rgba(0,0,0,0.9),url(bg.jpg));
background-repeat: no-repeat;
background-size: cover;
background-attachment: fixed;
height: 100vh;
opacity:0.1;
```

Answer (score -1):

check this one.

```css
.main { 
  
  background: url("https://cdn.pixabay.com/photo/2015/04/23/22/00/tree-736885__480.jpg");
    background-image: linear-gradient(166deg, rgba(0,0,0,0.6),rgb(17 29 251 / 90%)),url(https://cdn.pixabay.com/photo/2015/04/23/22/00/tree-736885__480.jpg);
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-size: cover;
  background-attachment: fixed;
  height: 100vh;
}
```

```html
<div class="main"> </div>
```